# How to use Squid(Proxy and reverse proxy) with joomla

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, joomla

i want some optimization tips on joomla performance i used memcache but i dont now how to use proxy and reverse proxy () with joomla please help Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using nginx rather than Squid?  It's configuration is pretty easy and it's very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Squid is the best solution for your need, we had the same performance problem with our sites and after using NginX web-server for both load-balancing between multiple web-servers and serving our dynamic files with PHP-FPM (which is very fast BTW) it seems to be solved.

Memcache is a very good solution but in fact it's not possible to use it with joomla when you have multiple servers (because of the cache duplications that may slow down your site even worse than now). Instead, we used Joomla'a native `Page Cache` and module-component `progressive cache` together and we also shared the cache folder between our servers. Now modules are being cached separately and when a request comes to a page, joomla creates a full page cache out of it with help of pre-cached modules which seems to be fast enough.

Our load-time of 12s is now about 600ms.